# Memcached Client for .NET/C# - what are the pros and cons of each?

Tags: windows, memcached

Several .NET Based Windows Memcached clients are listed on the Memcached Wiki:

http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/Clients

What are the pros and cons of each and which would you recommend for performance and ease of use?  Windows 7/Server 2008 Environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer

https://github.com/enyim/EnyimMemcached

Seems to be the only C# Memcache Client in active development (the Memcached wiki page is very out of date)

Enyim  seems to be the most feature rich client and is also the most feature rich:

http://sysdot.wordpress.com/2011/03/08/memcached-clients-which-ones-best/

Comment: Although in the end I went for Redis which I found to have much higher performance than Memcached.